# Using PDFBox 2.0.8 how to find if there is any overlapping texts present in the document?

Tags: pdfbox

[image: Refer the attached image]

I am using PDFBox 2.0.8, I am able to identify the text position of character, but it does not help to determine if there is an overlapping text. Example: "in excess o$f1 ,000.96". As you can see the $ symbol overlaps on "of", but how to predict that there is an overlap?

Comment: is "in excess o$f1 ,000.96" what you see in the PDF or is it what you get programmatically? Can you share your PDF? Did you try the sort option?

Comment: What is your use case? Do you create the PDF in question in one go from scratch? Then there is no need to fear overlapping words if you did not introduce bugs. Or do you add text onto existing PDFs with existing text? Then there is a certain danger of overlaps...

Comment: "in excess o$f1 ,000.96" is what I get programmatically using TextPosition. I have attached an image extract from the PDF to visualize how it appears in the PDF, but I cannot share the PDF.

Comment: My case to validate one PDF document and find out if the document is having text overlapping. The PDF in question is generated from Mainframe, and PDFBox is not able to retrieve any graphical information, like bounding rectangle, non-stroking color etc.from it. If I am retrieving using showTextString method of  (PDFGraphicsStreamEngine), then it is retrieving "including" and '$4,835.96" separately. But retrieving the text using Text position is giving "includin$g4, 835.96*". So, how to infer that the texts are overlapping.

Comment: Without the PDF that is pure guesswork. As you cannot share the PDF, you'll have to find out yourself.

Comment: Can you share a strategy to follow to identify it myself? I have shared the extract of TextPosition method, screenshot of how does it look in PDF, extract of show text method, also mentioned that there is no glyph/bounding box present in it. In addition, the PDF does not have any acrofields, so there is no possibility of overlapping acrofields present in it. If you have come across this situation then share your way of finding the overlapping text.

Comment: Simply inspect all content streams that might be involved and find the instructions responsible for that. I'm not aware of a short cut.

Comment: A strategy I can think of is to expand the DrawPrintTextPositions example (see source code download). Use the bounding boxes of the cyan paths and check whether any of these overlaps. The problem is that there may be legitimate overlappings.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workable solution myself to the problem that I have reported. While processing the List, I have added following condition that verifies if there is an overlapping of text. This solution may not work for all kinds of pdf documents, some additional work might need to be done:
         `if(textPositions.indexOf(position)+1<textPositions.size()){ if(position.contains(textPositions.get(textPositions.indexOf(position)+1))){overlappingTextFlag = true}}`

---

public boolean contains(TextPosition tp2)
Determine if this TextPosition logically contains another (i.e. they overlap and should be rendered on top of each other).
Parameters:
tp2 - The other TestPosition to compare against
Returns:
True if tp2 is contained in the bounding box of this text.